# PHP: Using a string 'address' of a value in an array get the value

Tags: php, arrays, string, indexing

I have a person array, with a key 'n' for name.  The value for 'n' is an array, with key 'l' (short for 'last') having the value I want to get at, the last name.

For curious programming reasons, I have "address" of the last name as a *string*.

How do I do this?
I've tried eval, among others.

SORRY I wasn't being clear!!

What I want is to use the variable $test to get it.

E.g. something like:

```
$person[$test]
```

(which obviously doesn't work, but what does?)

`$test` won't always be 'two deep'.  E.g. sometimes it will be `['a']['residential']['street']`

```
<?php

    $test = "['n']['l']";

    echo "I've got a string with the array index ".$test. "\n";

    $person = array("n"=>array('l'=>'SMITH'));

    echo 'the array, $person, is this: '."\n";
    print_r($person);

    echo "What I want is ".$person['n']['l']. "\n";
    ?>
```

Output:

```
I've got a string with the array index ['n']['l']
the array, $person, is this: 

    Array
    (
        [n] => Array
            (
                [l] => SMITH
            )

    )
```

What I want is SMITH

Comment: I am not entirely sure what it is your question is. You show that you are able to access $person['n']['l'], but it seems like this is your questions.

Comment: You're already doing that, what's wrong?

Comment: I do not clear your question, but I definitely do not want to display the contents of an array within an echo, but you must use the print_r() http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: I guess op wants to use `$test` variable to get the array positions instead of using static `['n']['l']` on the `echo ... $person['n']['l']` part.

Comment: removed the mongodb tag since it had has nothing to do with this question (even if that's where the data is coming from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have only two options:

Using [eval](http://php.net/manual/function.eval.php):

```
function IAmEvilSoYouShouldNotCallMe($array, $key) {
    return eval('return $array' . $key . ';');
}

echo IAmEvilSoYouShouldNotCallMe(
    array("n"=>array('l'=>'SMITH')),
    "['n']['l']"
);
```

Or string parsing:

```
function helper($array, $key) {
    $keys = array_map(function ($val) {
        return trim($val, "]['");
    }, explode('][', $key));    

    while ($key = array_shift($keys)) {
        if (isset($array[$key])) {
            $array = $array[$key];
            continue;
        }

        return null;
    }

    return $array;
}

echo helper(
    array("n"=>array('l'=>'SMITH')),
    "['n']['l']"
);
```

Both output:

```
SMITH
```

Comment: I ended up going this route so I didn't have to use eval.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will make this work the way you expect it to:

This will output SMITH - see http://codepad.org/M3jRDg99

```
eval("echo \$person$test;");
```

I assume that maybe the reason it didn't work for you had to do with escaping dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  To assign a variable within eval, I just did:  `eval("\$foo= \$person$test;");`

Comment: @Dan Note that you should be very carefull with using eval. Better to not use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no legitimate reason to use arrays in this case, you are only complicating your coding life. What you need to learn is Object Oriented Programming (OOP).

Then you would only have to create a People object that would contain an array of Person objects.

In the simplest form you would get a person name simply with a

```
People->listOfPersons[0]->fullName->familyName
```

or even better with getters and setters :

```
People->getNextPerson()->getFamilyName()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$index1 = $test[2];    
$index2 = $test[7];

echo $person[$index1][$index2];
```

Comment: obvieusly, this is provided his string has always the same structure and just different index names, otherwise I doubt there is a way to do that...

Comment: He could use regular expressions.

Comment: There would be simillar issues with regex. I assumed the structure of the $person array is always the same, so is the $test string (Always ['index_1']['index_2']). I would rather ask the question what is the point of doing that, why would indexes change etc?